# Print numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a random numpy array that i want to print out beside the player name. Right now it prints out the entire array beside a single player where I want to print all elements from index 0 with player 0, then increment the player and print out the second row of elements etc.

```
import numpy as np
import random

startPosition = []
for i in range (5):
    r = random.randint(1,5)
    if r not in startPosition: startPosition.append(r)

stats = np.random.randint(10,20,(5, 3))
d = {};

x = 5
while x > len(d):
    name = raw_input('Enter player name')
    d[name] = "";
names = d.keys()

from numpy  import array
arr = array(d)



for x in names:
    print  "Player:", x,",Scores:", ('\n'.join([''.join(['{:4}'.format(item) for item in row]) 
      for row in stats]))
```

Comment: You mean something like `for player, score in zip(players, scores): print(player, score)` ?

Comment: I find it interesting that you use a dict for player names (I'm guessing to ensure there are 5 unique ones) but don't store anything useful as the dict values. For this you can just use `set()`. That said, if you're already using a dict, why not just use that to associate an array of scores with each player? Rather than make a single 5x3 array, when each player is added to the dict create a single 3 element array of their scores and associate it with that player. Then you can loop over `d.items()`

Comment: BTW for the parts where you compute random `startPositions` you could use something like [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

Comment: Thank you DeepSpace that worked well, @Iguananaut, it has to be a unique name and will random.shuffle give me a random unique number or is there a chance of getting a same one ? I'm simply following the requirements for the assignment, instructor wants to create a random 5x3 array after I create a players dict.